# How can we setup correct tracking in Google Analytics for Netlify?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, netlify

Currently, I have added the GA Tag in our Tag Manager in our Netlify website and it is recording/firing the first page. But as I am visiting the other pages, the GA real time tracking still remains on the first page. Here is the current field name that I have for GTM: [image]

Comment: Do you have some JS handling page transitions? If so, try adding the "History Change" trigger to your PageView tag.

Comment: Hi @GeoffAtkins , thanks for this quick reply, here is what I have done for the history change trigger **This trigger fires on New History Fragment contains {{Page Path}}#{{New History Fragment}}** but still there's no change in the real-time pageview in GA